# Oracle multimedia resize image to smaller size and try to keep the quality as good as posible

Tags: oracle, image-processing, plsqldeveloper

How to reduce image size while having the best possible quality?
My original image has a resolution of `2848 x 4288 px` and a size of `10 MB`.
I need to reduce the original image to a format of `800x1200 px` and to reduce the size of the image under `1 MB`.

What I have tried has worked to reduce the resolution to `800 x 1200 px` and the size of the image under `1 MB` but the quality of the image is very bad.

**My code is as follows:**

```
DECLARE
    obj ORDSYS.ORDImage;
BEGIN
 --set obj with picture to process
  SELECT p.Picture INTO obj FROM TEST_PICTURE p
  WHERE p.id = 150287842167443049488278380264193152579 FOR UPDATE;

   obj.process('fileFormat=JPEG');
   obj.process('rotate 90');
   obj.process('fixedScale 1424 2144');
   obj.process('compressionFormat=JPEG,compressionQuality=MAXIN‌​TEGRITY');

--update processed image to blob column that i need to post on web
   UPDATE TEST_PICTURE SET picture_blob =ordsys.ordimage.getContent(obj) 
   WHERE id=150287842167443049488278380264193152579;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Is there anything i need to add to the code? Is this even possible to do using *ORACLE MULTIMEDIA IMAGE PROCESSING*? 
I think it is, as there are a lot of free applications that do image optimization. This is supposed to work like those web image optimizers.

[Something like this.](https://tinypng.com/)

This is what i get: low quality
  [[image]]

This is what i need:good quality
 [image]

Comment: The problem line is quite self-explanatory; `obj.process('compressionFormat=JPEG,compressionQuality=MAXCOMPRATIO');`

Comment: even if i put obj.process('compressionFormat=JPEG,compressionQuality=MAXINTEGRITY'); the Quality is stil low as the above image.